Surface reconstruction from unorganized point cloud via pcl::MarchingCubesHoppe results in non-manifold surfaces
I have an unorganized, isotropic and volumetric point cloud, which I get from a uniformely dense and noise-free simulated CT scan of a halfed apple (without stem) and try to get a concave mesh with the MC Hoppe reconstruction algorithm from PCL. What I am getting though is a mesh that is completely
or partially sliced-through at frequent locations of the mesh, both vertically and horizontally:
Top view with slice "holes" that go all the way through the mesh.
Small area of the front view with weird vertical/horizontal slice patterns.
I don't do anything special code-wise:
// Define search tree
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree = pcl::make_shared<pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>>();
tree->setInputCloud(m_impl->pointCloud);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals = pcl::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>>();

// Normal calculation
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> n;
n.setInputCloud(m_impl->pointCloud);
n.setSearchMethod(tree);
n.setKSearch(20);
n.compute(*cloud_normals);
pcl::concatenateFields(*m_impl->pointCloud, *cloud_normals, *m_impl->preprocessedCloud);
//[...]
// Surface reconstruction
float dist_ignore = -1, percentage_extend_grid = 0.05, iso_level = 0.0;
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr tree = pcl::make_shared<pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>>();
tree->setInputCloud(m_impl->preprocessedCloud);

pcl::MarchingCubesHoppe<pcl::PointNormal> mch(dist_ignore, percentage_extend_grid, iso_level);
mch.setInputCloud(m_impl->preprocessedCloud);
mch.setIsoLevel(iso_level);
mch.setSearchMethod(tree);
mch.setPercentageExtendGrid(percentage_extend_grid);
mch.setGridResolution(64, 64, 64);

I have also changed the point type to PointXYZI to use the intensity values going from 0.0 to 1.0 to provide a better surface context, but the class doesn't seem to use it at all, as nothing changes. The image resolution is 64x64 with 64 slices and increasing the grid resolution to 128x128x128 as a way to close the gaps also does not help and produces this hole-filled monstrosity. Do I do something wrong with the normal calculation or any other parts of the code/parameter choice?
Thank you in advance. If I forgot to provide an important detail, let me know.
Edit:
I am using PCL version 1.12.1 and my point cloud can be found here. I actually made an error in calling it isotropic as the point cloud is halfed, but the problem still stands.
Edit:
I just found out that the library is printing out stuff. I don't normally look at this as I am only using the Qt GUI and it does actually say:
Failed to find match for field 'intensity'.
Failed to find match for field 'normal_x'.
Failed to find match for field 'normal_y'.
Failed to find match for field 'normal_z'.
Failed to find match for field 'curvature'. 

Probably the culprit.
Edit:
The workaround @IBitMyBytes proposed worked. The Hoppe MC can't handle very volumetric point clouds. pcl::ConcaveHull (alpha shapes) can be used instead or before applying the MC:
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::point_t>::Ptr tree = pcl::make_shared<pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>>();
tree->setInputCloud(m_impl->pointCloud);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr concaveCloud = pcl::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>();;
pcl::ConcaveHull<pcl::PointXYZ> concave;
concave.setInputCloud(m_impl->pointCloud);
concave.setAlpha(0.09);
concave.setSearchMethod(tree);
concave.reconstruct(*concaveCloud);


This might be a problem with inconsistent normal orientation. Can you make your input point cloud available for testing? Also (maybe relevant): which PCL version are you using?

@IBitMyBytes thank you for your help, I have edited the post and added the point cloud file.

The "Failed to find" messages only say that some fields of your cloud can't be filled because the file (or PCLPointCloud2) does not contain this information. I think this is not a problem because intensity and curvature are not used anyway, and you estimate the normals yourself.
I am not sure if this kind of point cloud, where the points are not only on the surface of the object, is usable with the MarchingCubesHoppe class. You could try to remove the points inside via ConcaveHull, and then use marching cubes on the remaining surface points.

You are absolutely right. I have just looked into the first sentence in the original paper, that is referenced in the PCL documentation, which the implementation seems to be based on. It states "We describe and demonstrate an algorithm that takes as input an unorganized set of points [...] on or near an unknown Manifold M.". I am going to try your workaround.
